# Like function not parsing correctly in sql

Tags: sql, sql-like, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a string in below:

```
string_col

FT PROMOTED TREND - TTT_TLMW+_WER_TEST_TEST_TEsT_TEST CHECK_ANOTHER_NA_TEST_TEST: TEST_TEST_TEST_TEST_FIVE
```

My function below is supposed to remove the first `_` and anything before it if the condition applies: `_TTT_` appears.

When I write the function:

```
CASE WHEN string_col LIKE '%_TTT_%' THEN RIGHT(string_col, LENGTH(string_col) - CHARINDEX('_', string_col)) ELSE string_col END new_string_col
```

The output removes the TTT_ at the beginning when it shouldn't:

```
TLMW+_WER_TEST_TEST_TEsT_TEST CHECK_ANOTHER_NA_TEST_TEST: TEST_TEST_TEST_TEST_FIVE
```

The expected output should be no change.

Any idea why this may be?

EDIT:

```
14_TTT_two_dmeD
```

Putting brackets around the [_] is not removing anything before TTT for other rows I have.

Comment: I ran this on SQL Server 2016 and I got the 'no change' results as expected. Not sure why you aren't. Unless the underscore is representing something else besides and underscore.

Comment: The underscore is a placeholder for any char.

Comment: This is, actually, a good question @nak5120! It is so easy to forget that `_` has a wildcard meaning.

Comment: Thanks, using this method, I ran into a new issue. It is not removing the `14_ before TTT`: Expected output is `TTT_two_dmeD` - showing edit in question

Comment: @nak5120 Using my query, it works just fine and removes 14_ just fine. See https://rextester.com/HIIN97385 example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIKE '%_TTT_%'` means there exists `TTT`inside the string with any char before and any char after it.
If you want to specify the underscore char, you need to escape it:

```
LIKE '%[_]TTT[_]%'
```

Edit:
If you want to remove everything before `TTT_`:

```
CASE 
    WHEN string_col LIKE '%_TTT[_]%' 
      THEN RIGHT(string_col, LEN(string_col) - CHARINDEX('TTT_', string_col) + 1) 
      ELSE string_col 
END new_string_col
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5581690576af5ad9c9c38c3b0329ca18).
To remove everything before the 1st `_`:

```
RIGHT(string_col, LEN(string_col) - CHARINDEX('_', string_col) + 1)
```

**Edit**:

```
select 
  CASE 
    WHEN string_col LIKE '%_TTT[_]%' 
      THEN RIGHT(string_col, LEN(string_col) - CHARINDEX('TTT_', string_col) + 1) 
    WHEN string_col LIKE '%_DSD[_]%' 
      THEN RIGHT(string_col, LEN(string_col) - CHARINDEX('DSD_', string_col) + 1) 
    ELSE string_col 
  END new_string_col
from tablename
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192594/discussion-on-answer-by-forpas-like-function-not-parsing-correctly-in-sql).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the database you are using, for example SQL Server, `_` may have a [meaning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/wildcard-match-one-character-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

You might want to escape the underscore in your LIKE statement.

**Example of SQL Server**

```
create table test (
  string_col varchar(1000)
);
insert into test values ('FT PROMOTED TREND - TTT_TLMW+_WER_TEST_TEST_TEsT_TEST CHECK_ANOTHER_NA_TEST_TEST: TEST_TEST_TEST_TEST_FIVE');
insert into test values ('FT PROMOTED TREND2 - _TTT_TLMW+_WER_TEST_TEST_TEsT_TEST CHECK_ANOTHER_NA_TEST_TEST: TEST_TEST_TEST_TEST_FIVE');
```

**Result**

```
select * from test
where string_col LIKE '%_TTT_%';
```

will give you 2 results.

```
select * from test
where string_col LIKE '%[_]TTT[_]%';
```

will give you 1 result.

**Maybe your query should look like this**

```
select
    CASE
    WHEN string_col LIKE '%[_]TTT[_]%' THEN RIGHT(string_col, LEN(string_col) - CHARINDEX('_', string_col))
    ELSE string_col
    END new_string_col
from test;
```

if you are using SQL Server. If you are using a different database, you might have ways to escape that `_` as well.